# Export a man page in pdf

Tags: pdf, man, postscript

Doing `man -t man > man.ps` will export the man page for man in postscript.

How can I export it in PDF?

I have gone through the manuals and learnt about the `-T` option but it's a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `groff` and `gropdf` exists on your Linux system, you should be able to use

```
man -Tpdf man >man.pdf
```

(note the absence of a space between `-T` and `pdf`)

On an Ubuntu system, it should be enough to install the `groff` package to get access to `gropdf`.

The option argument to `-T` is passed on to `groff` and `groff` will use *its* `-T` option with the same option argument.  So, read the `groff` manual about `-T` for more info.

On systems using [`mandoc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandoc), the `groff` utility does not need to be installed for the above command to work since the `mandoc` utility (called by `man`) would convert the manual to PDF by itself.

Comment: I'm using Debian Stretch and installing only the groff package provides access to gropdf.

Comment: Under Fedora you need to install groff-perl package on top of groff for gropdf to work.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have `ghostscript` package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

You would need to convert the postscript to the PDF; for the command `last` that would be:

```
man -t last | ps2pdf - last.pdf
```

Comment: This works for me too but the above procedure suits me more, though I will use it for other purposes - thanks.

Comment: This would convert the Postscript output of `man` to PDF. This would work, and for text documents it may be adequate.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, ps2pdf is installed by default.